# How can I define and call this code as a function?

Tags: c, function, memory-management, c-strings, cs50

I'm new to programming.Im learning from CS50. I'm not sure on how to define this code as a function.I want the function to return key[n].And how to call the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    int n = strlen(argv[1]);
    int key[n];
    int k =0;

    for( int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        if(islower(argv[1][i]) != 0)

        {
            for(int j = 97; j < argv[1][i]; j++)
            {
                k++;
            }
            key[i] = k;
            k = k*0;
        }

        if(isupper(argv[1][i]) != 0)
        {
            for(int j = 65; j < argv[1][i]; j++)
            {
                k++;
            }
            key[i] = k;
            k = k*0;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How to define and call functions should be explained in any decent C book or tutorial.

Comment: You have already defined one function and that is `main`. Now define one more.

Comment: Are you asking how to return an array from a function?  You can't, exactly, and several questions already here on SO cover the details and alternatives.

Comment: Your lower-case key mapping loop and assignment `for(int j = 97; j < argv[1][i]; j++)
            {
                k++;
            }
            key[i] = k;` and be reduced to `key[i] = argv[1][i] - 'a';`, avoiding a magic number as well.  You can make similar changes to the upper-case key mapping loop.  Using `k = k * 0;` is a silly way of writing `k = 0;`.  If you were going to keep the variable (you aren't), you should define it inside each `if` block and initialize it to zero, rather than set it to zero after you've used it.

Comment: Should you check for and object to non-alpha characters in the string?

Answer (score 1):

The function can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int * f( const char *s )
{
    int *key = NULL;

    size_t n = strlen( s );

    if ( n != 0 && ( key = calloc( n, sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            unsigned char c = s[i];

            if ( islower( c ) ) key[i] = c - 'a';
            if ( isupper( c ) ) key[i] = c - 'A';
        }
    }

    return key;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
    if ( argc == 2 ) 
    {
        int *key = f( argv[1] );
        if (key != NULL)
        {
            // some other code
            free( key );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler In fact the if statement is not required because the statements commented like "some other code" can include the if statement.:)

Comment: But to help a novice user, it is as well to be explicit about the null check which they otherwise might not infer as being necessary.  Your answer — your choice.

Answer (score 0):

A function is a block of code with an "in" and "out". You define a function to receive values from the outside with syntax like `int key (int example){}` and pass in values to your function call with `key(1);`.

Your main() is also a function. The values that main() receives are being used in your code right now.

Your own function (which you define outside of main()) can be done in many ways, but the easiest would be to simply keep almost all of the same code within main() while figuring out how to transport what main() received into yours.